# Does javascript and node.js engines internal working differ

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I am  trying to understand internal working of javascript and node.js v8 engines, I understand both use single thread event loop. And javascript engine uses execution context loaded into call stack.

This figure is my reference to understand internal working of JS
[image]

And node.js maintains thread pool etc, so internal working of node.js  and JS is different? Is my understanding correct , can someone briefly explain?

Answer (score 2):

Someone will definitely explain this better, but "JS" is a programming language,that can be run on various interpreters (or engines), while "node.js" is an execution environment designed to run "JS" programs on a server environment, using "V8" as its interpreter.

Here's a list of JS engines: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines

What is node JS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js

Comment: Hi , thanks for your answer, I want to understand differences in their internal working :)